# problem with my cloth

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PrSWh0ebyCM but when I go to bake all the result is this. Please help me *
[image]

[image]

this is the project [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. decrease thickness outer of your model to minimum value

[image]

2. increase quality steps of your cloth to 40

[image]

3. enjoy result:

[image]

Comment: thank you Chris

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: do you know ho to fix the problem, at the sleeve height and in various places the Mesh do not close.